# how to verify unix wait and then run next command

Tags: shell, unix, parallel-processing, ksh

I have 2 processes that will run in the background. I think I'm using wait correctly. I'm not sure, however I want to make sure both are complete before running the next statement (4.sql). How do I check for that? So far I have this:

```
1.sql
2.sql &
pid2=$!
echo "Waiting for PID:$pid2"
3.sql &
pid3=$!
echo "Waiting for PID:$pid3"
4.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to already be familiar with the `wait` command?

```
1.sql
2.sql &
pid2=$!
echo "Waiting for PID:$pid2"
3.sql &
pid3=$!
echo "Waiting for PID:$pid3"
wait $pid2 $pid3   # <---- This is new
4.sql
```